# IE 11 & Office 365 - getting Excel to open instead of being prompted

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, office365, internet-explorer-11

Windows 10, IE 11, Office 365

**Desired behavior:**  From a website that runs reports (Crystal, but inside a custom web application), click on View Report button, Excel opens in a new window and report is displayed in Excel.  Works this way on the same system but only when using Firefox.

**What IE does:**
Click on button to View Report, a new window opens, user is prompted "*What do you want to do with xxxxx.xls*" and the options **Open (The file won't automatically be saved)**, **Save**, and **Save As**.  Click on **Open**, Get a message at the bottom of the browser saying "*Do you want to save xxxxxx.xls*" with the only options being **Save** or **Save As**. **Save and Open** (third option) is not available.  Click **Save**, then am prompted to **Open**, **Open Folder** or **View Downloads**.  Clicking **Open** opens Excel and the report displays fine.   (3 clicks to open in excel).    Prior to installation of Office 365, IE 11 performed the same way as Firefox.

To my knowledge, I have the appropriate security settings selected.  Any idea why this might have simply stopped working?  Since Firefox works, I do not believe the issue is with configuration of Excel.

Any help, thoughts, etc. appreciated.

Comment: I didn't reproduce the issue in my IE version 11.719.18362.0, update version 11.0.180. I also install office 365. It might be some settings of IE having changed. You could try to reset IE settings according to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings). I think the answer below is also helpful and you can try it. Besides, you could also refer to [this similar thread](https://superuser.com/questions/246553/how-to-disable-file-download-popup-in-internet-explorer).

Comment: Please select an answer to help users with the same issue find the solution.

Comment: So far, neither option has worked completely.  With the registry setting, I am no longer getting the Open/Save/Save As window, but I do get the Save in the orange box at the bottom of IE, followed by another orange box to Open.

Comment: It looks like IE or Office 365 is configured as the default app to open excel file in your system. You could check the default apps in your system. Besides, there's an [official guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/162059/how-to-configure-internet-explorer-to-open-office-documents-in-the-app) to fix a similar issue, you could try the solutions in it.

Answer (score 0):

I hate linking a text picture, but that's what I found unfortunately.

src: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/6fea6fc0-7987-47d7-a002-d73a90b1debb/asking-what-do-you-want-to-do-with-this-file?forum=ieitprocurrentver

[image]